Minimal Discriminants Quadratic Fields
I am currently working on a topic related to discriminants of quadratic fields and would greatly appreciate your expertise.
My question is the following:
What are the minimal absolute discriminants of quadratic fields $K$ in the following cases:

$K$ is imaginary ($\Delta_K < 0$) with a second $3$-class group having coclasses $r = 2, 4, 6, 8$.

$K$ is real ($\Delta_K > 0$) with a second $3$-class group having coclasses $r = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$.


In both cases, I specify that the $3$-class group $\mathrm{Cl}_3(K)$ is elementary bicyclic, meaning $\mathrm{Cl}_3(K) \cong \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.
I know that for $r = 2$ (imaginary) and $r = 1$ (real), the discriminants can be easily found by taking the smallest possible values:
$\Delta_K = -1627$ for $r = 2$, $K$ imaginary.
$\Delta_K = 229$ for $r = 1$, $K$ real.
However, for other values of $r$, I am encountering difficulties and would like to know if any of you have worked on similar problems or if there are specific tools or references to address this issue.
If you have any ideas, references (papers, databases such as LMFDB, tools like PARI/GP or Magma), or even concrete examples, I would be very grateful!
Additional Issue:
I am also trying to compute these discriminants using the PARI/GP tool. My script calculates the class groups for different discriminants, but I am facing a syntax error in my GP script that prevents it from running correctly. Specifically, the error I receive is:
***   syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting )-> or ',' or ')':
***   for(d=3,20000,

Here is the relevant part of the script:
x = variable();
for(d = 3, 20000,
  if (issquarefree(-d),
    try(
      my(bnf = bnfinit(x^2 - d, 1));
      print("Structure de bnf pour d = ", d, ": ", bnf);
      if (type(bnf) == "bnf",
        my(C3 = bnf.clgp);
        print("Groupe de classes: ", C3);
        if (C3 && #C3 == 2 && C3[1] == 3 && C3[2] == 3,
          write("resultats.txt", Str("Discriminant: ", -d, "  Groupe de classes: ", C3));
        )
      )
    )
    , print("Erreur pour d = ", d, " : ", E)
  )
)

Thank you in advance for your insights.
